# How can I code using google protobuf and decode?(google apps script)

Tags: google-apps-script, protocol-buffers

I'm deploying an aplicattion in Google Apps Script, and I need to code with the buffer and de-code. How can I do?

Comment: Good question.  I've never used protocol buffers before.  Have you asked questions about it [here](https://groups.google.com/g/protobuf)  The documentation doesn't anything about apps script that I can see although it does talk about a [javascript](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/javascript-generated) browser base solution but nothing said about server side google apps script.  I follow this question.

Comment: It will be similar to as if you did it in a browser app. You'll need to generate the JS proto (via `protoc`) and bundle it with it's dependences into your apps script.